# Indecision about the minimization of automata

Tags: minimize, finite-automata

I have to minimize some finite state automata but I was born a doubt: before this transformation the automata must be proved ε-productions? Or can I leave them?

The automata is this: [this http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/3fad/yk24smo642ozob0fg.jpg](http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/3fad/yk24smo642ozob0fg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The standard minimization algorithm works on deterministic finite automata.  The lambda transitions mean this is not a DFA.  So you must eliminate the lambdas first.

It's pretty easy to see this machine accepts a*|ab.  The DFA for this is pretty easy to design and minimize intuitively.

Or you can go through the formal algorithms for NFA-lambda to DFA conversion followed by minimization.

Comment: Oh thanks! What are the preconditions for minimizing a finite state automaton? 
According to me these are but I'm not sure that is correct then correct me if I'm wrong: the automaton must not have unreachable states, the automaton should not have unnecessary states, the automaton must be total, the automaton must be deterministic. So the precondition so that an automaton is deterministic is that it does not contain epsilon productions? 
Well I didn't know. Thank you very much

Comment: @user3808470 Deleting unreachable states and unnecessary states are parts of minimization. I don't know what you mean by "total."  The automaton must meet the definition of a DFA, which is more than just saying it's deterministic.